# How to use -Werror= to make compiler throw errors for all -Wimplicit-int-conversion warnings?

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-warnings

I am not sure what should go on the right side of the equal sign for:

```
-Werror=<what_should_go_here?>
```

Should it be

```
-Werror=implicit-int-conversion
```

or

```
-Werror=-Wimplicit-int-conversion
```

or something else?

Comment: What did the documentation say? Why do you feel it is unclear? A mispelled option will never cause undefined behaviour. Even in case of potential UB, it is best practice to check the behaviour as long as you don't assume that there is no UB.

Answer (score -1):

This works with `clang++`, but not with `g++`

```
clang++ test.cc -Wall -Wextra -std=c++11 -Wimplicit-int-conversion -Werror
```

Comment: This is just showing the warning, which I already know how to do. My question is about "Werror="